# F# Interactive hotkeys in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, f#, f#-interactive

When developing in F# there are two main actions I keep doing all the time:

1. Switching between development (the code window) and F# Interactive. I'd like to know if there is some kind of hotkey that'll allow me to toggle between them, so I dont have to use the mouse? That certainly breaks my workflow.
2. I feel the urge to constantly clear up FSI (the option you find when right clicking and selecting the Clear All command). I've looked up in Visual Studio Keyboard options but I can't find the Clear All command in the commands list.

Do hotkeys exist for any these actions? If not, would defining macros for them help me in any way?

Thanks

Comment: Is "clear command" "reset session"?

Comment: No, "clear command" is what makes everything that's printed in FSI disappear. EDIT: I mean "Clear all".

Comment: CTRL+TAB will cycle through the tool windows--not exactly a hot key though.

Comment: Hmmm. Nice! It's only a couple of key strokes, so it's way better than having to use the mouse. I wonder if there's a way to record this as a macro, though.

Answer (score 6):

CTRL+Alt+F activates FSI. This, in a macro, would also do it:

```
DTE.Windows.Item("{DEE22B65-9761-4A26-8FB2-759B971D6DFC}").Activate() 'F# Interactive
```

CTRL+Tab will put you back in the editor (assuming that's where you were before).

Comment: F7 also puts you back in the editor for many of the VS keybinding templates.

Comment: @Daniel : Hm, it does for me... To be clear, for me, F7 is the keybinding for the View->Code menu item.

Comment: No clue about the "Clear all" shortcut, though?

Comment: Nope. Couldn't find a shortcut for that.